# Download PDF Files - Socket Error

Tags: java, file, download

I have a little problem, I have this method to download files in two formats (. Txt and. PDF).

For files in. Txt'm not having problems.

But for PDF files when I cancel download or when he opens the download window and I make no action, the code is giving this exception:

For Time waiting a user action:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:99)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunkTransfer(ChunkOutput.java:578)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunks(ChunkOutput.java:548)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.flush(ChunkOutput.java:436)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput$2.checkForFlush(ChunkOutput.java:657)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.write(ChunkOutput.java:342)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.write(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:148)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:151)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:59)
at FIRST.handlers.FRC.downloadFile(FRC.java:752)
at FIRST.handlers.FRC.handleDownloadPDFItem(FRC.java:638)
at FIRST.handlers.FRC.handleRequest(FRC.java:368)
at FIRST.FIRSTApplication.serviceRequest(FIRSTApplication.java:47)
at FIRST.FIRSTONLINE.service(FIRSTONLINE.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:845)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:236)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3284)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2091)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

And this when the user cancel the download file:

```
java.net.SocketException: socket write error: Connection reset by peer.
at jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.writeBytesPinned(Native Method)
at jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.socketWrite(SocketNativeIO.java:46)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(SocketOutputStream.java)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunkTransfer(ChunkOutput.java:577)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunks(ChunkOutput.java:548)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.flush(ChunkOutput.java:436)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput$2.checkForFlush(ChunkOutput.java:657)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.write(ChunkOutput.java:342)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.write(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:148)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:151)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:58)
at FIRST.handlers.FRC.downloadFile(FRC.java:752)
at FIRST.handlers.FRC.handleDownloadPDFItem(FRC.java:638)
at FIRST.handlers.FRC.handleRequest(FRC.java:368)
at FIRST.FIRSTApplication.serviceRequest(FIRSTApplication.java:47)
at FIRST.FIRSTONLINE.service(FIRSTONLINE.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:235)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3284)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

This is my method:

```
private String downloadFile(String fileName, String name, String format) {
    String result = null;
    HttpServletResponse response = getHttpServletResponse();
    if (response != null) {

        if (format != null && format.contains(PDF_EXTENSION.getExtension())) {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
        } else {
            response.setContentType("application/text");
        }
        response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);

        FileInputStream fs = null;
        try {
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            byte[] b = new byte[8192];
            byte[] crlf = { 0x0d, 0x0a };
            int size = 0;

            while ((size = fs.read(b)) != -1) {
                if (format == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        if (b[i] == 0x0a) {
                            os.write(crlf);
                        } else {
                            os.write(b, i, 1);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    os.write(b);
                }
            }
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fs != null) {
                    fs.close();
                }

                if(isPDFFile(fileName)) {
                    deletePDFFileTemporary(fileName);
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        result = "application/text";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Have appreciate the help. thank you

Comment: `os.flush();` not `out.flush();`

Comment: I forgot to comment on this out.flush () is another structure on the OutputStream. The error always happens in  } else {                os.write(b);
                }

Comment: Today I performed some more analysis and figured the error does not happen in Chrome only on internet explorer 8. Could it be something connected to the response header?

Comment: By chance are you using jquery on the client?

Comment: No I used just html, the error it's happen inside the .write method

Comment: Add a "Content-Length" header.

Comment: I've tried doing this: response.setContentLength (fs.available ()); And I had the same result. Not know if this course, but my download works, but exceptions occur after about 2 minutes or when I cancel the download

Comment: Use file.length() not fs.available() the stream blocking doesn't effect the length.

Comment: I performed a test here and the error happened again :(

Comment: No one with any tips?